# How do i add hover event to the grid tiles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, hover

I am struggling to add a hover event or a event listener to all 9 childs, it also doesnt let me to add the cursor: 'pointer' to the elements but it adds the colors and other css styles. I have tried to add an mouseover event listener in js but that doesn't work either. Please let me know if you have a solution to this.

Here's my code:

```js
const gridEl = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-div");

gridEl.forEach((e) =>
  e.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    e.style.color = "black";
    console.log("clicked");
  })
);
```

```css
.grid-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-wifi"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-hot-tub-person"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-utensils"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-person-swimming"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-water"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-baseball-bat-ball"></i>
    <p class="grid-paragraph-top"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></i>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-div">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not provided any JS code to show your attempt at adding an `eventListener` for `mouseover` or anything else. Please update your question with all relevant code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better understand your problem

Comment: It seems to work for me. What do you want to see when you hover or click on your elements?

Comment: to change the color, also in the console it doesn't appear 'clicked' when i click on one of them

Comment: I've edited your post and added the code snippet. Since you're using fontawesome, I've added the fontawesome CDN. It seems to work?

Comment: ok i just took the grid and put it somewhere else just to see if it works, and indeed it does, i will put the whole section so you can see exactly whats going on. i also have a image dehind that zooms in and ot, depending on scroll. i will update the code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a grid of HTML elements such as divs, here's an example of how to add a hover event using JavaScript:

First, add a class to each grid tile element that you want to attach the hover event to. For example, let's say you want to add the class "grid-tile" to each tile:

```
<div class="grid-tile">Tile 1</div>
<div class="grid-tile">Tile 2</div>
<div class="grid-tile">Tile 3</div>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

Next, in your JavaScript code, you can use the querySelectorAll() method to select all elements with the "grid-tile" class, and then loop through them to attach the hover

```
event:


// select all grid tiles
const tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-tile');

// attach hover event to each tile
tiles.forEach(tile => {
  tile.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    // do something when tile is hovered over
    tile.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  });

  tile.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    // do something when tile is no longer being hovered over
    tile.style.backgroundColor = '';
  });
});
```

In the above example, we use the addEventListener() method to attach two events: mouseenter and mouseleave. When the mouse enters a tile, we change its background color to yellow. When the mouse leaves the tile, we reset its background color to its original value (empty string).

You can modify the code inside the event listeners to perform any actions you want when the tile is hovered over.

**Better yet**

If you're using a CSS framework like Bootstrap, you can also add a hover effect to grid tiles by using the built-in classes provided by the framework.

For example, if you're using Bootstrap, you can use the hover class to add a hover effect to any element. To apply this to grid tiles, you can add the class to each tile element:

```
<div class="grid-tile hover">Tile 1</div>
<div class="grid-tile hover">Tile 2</div>
<div class="grid-tile hover">Tile 3</div>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

In the above example, we've added the hover class to each tile element. This will cause the tile to change its background color when it's hovered over.

You can also customize the hover effect by using other built-in classes provided by Bootstrap, such as bg-primary to change the background color, or text-white to change the text color.

Here's an example that combines the hover class with the bg-primary and text-white classes to create a custom hover effect:

```
<div class="grid-tile hover bg-primary text-white">Tile 1</div>
<div class="grid-tile hover bg-primary text-white">Tile 2</div>
<div class="grid-tile hover bg-primary text-white">Tile 3</div>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

In the above example, we've added the bg-primary class to change the background color to the primary color defined in Bootstrap, and the text-white class to change the text color to white. When the tile is hovered over, the background color and text color will change to the specified values.

**The traditional CSS way**

Another way to add a hover event to grid tiles is by using CSS pseudo-classes.

You can use the :hover pseudo-class to add styles to an element when it's hovered over. To apply this to grid tiles, you can define a CSS rule that targets the .grid-tile:hover selector. For example:

```
.grid-tile:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

In the above example, we're using the :hover pseudo-class to apply a yellow background color to any element with the .grid-tile class when it's hovered over.

You can also combine this with other CSS properties to create custom hover effects. For example, you can add a transition effect to smoothly animate the change in background color:

```
.grid-tile {
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.grid-tile:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

In the above example, we've added a transition effect to the *background-color* property. This will cause the background color to smoothly transition from white to yellow when the tile is hovered over. The 0.3s value specifies the duration of the transition, and the ease-in-out value specifies the timing function.

You can experiment with different CSS properties to create your own custom hover effects.

**Frameworks**

If you're using a front-end framework like React, Vue.js, or Angular, you can add a hover event to grid tiles by using their built-in event handling mechanisms.

For example, in React, you can add an onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave event handlers to each tile component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Tile(props) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className="grid-tile"
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      style={{ backgroundColor: isHovered ? 'yellow' : 'white' }}
    >
      {props.label}
    </div>
  );
}

function Grid() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tile label="Tile 1" />
      <Tile label="Tile 2" />
      <Tile label="Tile 3" />
      {/* and so on... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above example, we're using the useState hook to keep track of whether the tile is currently being hovered over. We then add onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave event handlers to update the isHovered state based on whether the tile is being hovered over or not. Finally, we use the style attribute to set the background color of the tile based on the isHovered state.

You can customize the code inside the event handlers and the styles applied to the tile to create your own custom hover effect.

Similar approaches can be used in other front-end frameworks like Vue.js and Angular, using their respective event handling mechanisms.